# twitteR error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)

Tags: r, twitter, rcurl

I get the following error:

```
twitCred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")):

Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) :
 Could not resolve host: api.twitter.com; Host not found, try again
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Where are you running this? Do you have an internet connection on the machine?

Comment: I am running it on R language. Yes I have internet connection.

Comment: Is this an up-to-date version from GitHub? https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR